# If I marry an EU citizen in Sweden, how can I get a resident permit?

Tags: immigration

I am a non-eu citizen and my girlfriend is an eu citizen. We both came to Sweden last month and now we are planning to get married in Sweden. How do I get a resident permit? We already got the marriage license from the tax office. I am illegal in Sweden; can I apply for the resident permit?

Comment: Once you are married, your presence in Sweden should be unambiguously legal under the freedom of movement directive.  Whether Sweden will recognize that or not, I do not know.